# Python Flask-GoogleMaps where to change default region?

Tags: python, google-maps

I am using [flask google maps](https://github.com/rochacbruno/Flask-GoogleMaps) to display a google map.

I noticed that the default preferenced region is USA and that it can be changed in script. I need the region to be germany:

> When you load the Google Maps JavaScript API from maps.googleapis.com it applies a default bias for application behavior towards the United States. If you want to alter your application to serve different map tiles or bias the application (such as biasing geocoding results towards the region), you can override this default behavior by adding a region parameter to the  tag when loading the Maps JavaScript API code.

This needs to be changed because there are cities with the same name and for example the input "Potsdam" shows a city in the USA instead the city in germany.

As far as I understand the region argument has to be added here, my map in python:

```
mymap = Map(
        identifier="view-side",
        lat=location.latitude,
        lng=location.longitude,
        infobox=[],
        markers=[],
        zoom = 11
        )
```

I tried to add `region = "Germany"` but nothing happened.
There is no example in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly adding the `?region=DE` argument to the script did not work aswell, so I managed to solve it with a trick.

I simply added germany `"Deutschland"` to the location which the user searches.

Solution:

```
location = geolocator.geocode("Deutschland, " + findroomcity)
```

Answer (score 0):

Flask-GoogleMaps should be just a wrapper around the Google Maps API.
The [location documentation from the google maps api states:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization)

> Language localization
>
> By default, the Google Maps JavaScript API uses the user's preferred
>   language setting as specified in the browser, when displaying textual
>   information such as the names for controls, copyright notices, driving
>   directions and labels on maps. In most cases, it's preferable to
>   respect the browser setting. However, if you want the Maps JavaScript
>   API to ignore the browser's language setting, you can force it to
>   display information in a particular language by adding a language
>   parameter to the  tag when loading the Maps JavaScript API
>   code.
>
> The following example displays a map in Japanese and sets the region
>   to Japan:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&language=ja&region=JP">
```

So you could define the region in the javascript script tag where you load the google libary in your template.

A google region code is a [IANA language region subtag](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRegionCodes)

According to [this page](https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry) the region code for Germany should be **DE**

Answer (score 0):

Currently it seems googlemaps API do not provide the feature that you require.

But, in my opinion you should include country/region name in the search query so that it returns correct result. Correct search query (eg. Potsdam, Germany) is the solution here

Comment: Oh right.. Didn't check your answer before replying to the question. Cheers!